# Php file_exist with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use regex pattern to search for files.

Directory path is:

```
$css_dir = MY_PLUGIN_DIR.'/source/css/';
```

Css filename starts with:

```
$css_prefix = 'hap_css_';
```

and ends with:

```
'.css'
```

With some amount of unknown characters in between.

I dont know how to construct regex pattern with variable and how to construct file exist with regex.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use `hap_css_.+?\.css`?

Comment: I could, but I still need to construct file_exist with regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [glob()](http://php.net/glob):

```
$files = glob($css_dir . $css_prefix . '*.css');
```

However, you have to roll your own [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/directoryiterator) based solution for more complex filtering:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($css_dir);
$pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($css_prefix) . '.+\\.css$' . '/';
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
  if (preg_match($pattern, $fileInfo->getBaseName())) {
    // match!
  }
}
```

(One could also integrate a [RegexIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.regexiterator.php)):

The use of [scandir()](http://php.net/scandir) is possible as well:

```
$pattern = '/^' . preq_quote($css_prefix) . '.+\\.css$' . '/';

$files = array_filter(scandir($css_dir), function ($filename) {
  return preg_match($pattern, $filename);
});
```

Comment: Can I use glob to detect multiple files?

Comment: @Toniq Yes, you can. The [documentation](http://php.net/glob) says "Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error."

Comment: should be `preg_quote` not `preq_quote`